# How can I stop users from changing the content of my question?

Tags: discussion, policy, question-quality, questions, editing

I recently asked a question where I was asking how to solve a context of type A using a context of type B.My question was how to use context B.I didn't explain the exact context A because my question was more general than specific.I had some answers about this.Then,a user asked me to add more specific explanation for context A so they can help me solve context A more directly.I did so, but then another user reedited my question and removed my addition because the analysis of context A should be a new question.
My question here is:

**How can I control my own question when different users want my question to be different and they edit my question according to their aspects?**

Comment: Are you refering to [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/converting-math-problems-to-sat-instances)? It did start off awfully vague.

Comment: @Gilles Yes and agree to that but my question here is what happens when different users try to make my question more clear in different ways?Is that always an objective method?

Comment: The goals are to keep/make the question answerable and on-topic, to avoid invalidating existing answers, and to respect the original poster (roughly in this order of priority). Sometimes (as here) several solutions could work. I don't have much time to read through the whole history right now, I think given the existing answers the question should remain general, but it would be a good idea to keep your endgoal in.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks make it an answer please..

Comment: In your specific case, your question at first did not mention what the exact problem was you wanted to model. Your question had received 2 answers, and I think a general "how do I model a problem as SAT" is a very good question. I wouldn't have re-edited out your specific problem from the question if you hadn't posted a new question, where you were basically asking the same thing again. The existence of your new question was not justified if the original question had had the same question in there.

Comment: As for what to do about this in general, I don't know. A moderator can lock a question so it can't be edited. I think it is very rare that users would purposely change the meaning of a question. Usually people wait and let the OP clarify, because he is the only one who really knows what he meant in unclear cases.

Comment: @Juho It is true that in that case your intention was to remove any duplicate information appearing in my new question.Thanks!

Comment: relevant: [faq about editing](http://cs.stackexchange.com/faq#editing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a general answer. If someone is editing your question and you think they did it wrong, feel free to roll-back their changes.

Most likely there was some misunderstanding going on. I would recommend the following to improve your question after the roll-back.

- Try to make your question clearer. Check what the editor had got wrong and why. Extend or modify your question, such that other readers will not fall into the same "trap".
- If you don't know why your question was changed, post a comment and ask for the motivation for the changes.

You should note that almost all questions are edited by several authors to improve their quality, and sometimes something just might go wrong.

Comment: It helps if editors include in the edit message what their reasons were.